# How to add user with sudo privileges in Solaris

Tags: sudo, users, solaris

How would I add a user with `sudo` privileges in Solaris 10 and Solaris 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option:

1. Log in as a user which has full `sudo` privileges.
2. Fire up a terminal and type `sudo visudo`.
3. Add `user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to the end of the file (`user` here obviously implies the username of the user you want to give the privileges to).
4. Save the changes.

Second option:

`sudo usermod -aG sudo username`